# Setting variables on Javascript namespace from ASP.NET Webform code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to clean up some older code, and it currently uses variables set with ScriptManager for use in the Javascript code to show/hide parts of the page.

The variables are currently just `_showNameDiv`, etc.

I'd like to put these all onto a common namespace, to make things a little bit cleaner, such as `MyCompany.Toggles.ShowNameDiv`.

I tried to create a namespace

```
var MyCompany = { 
                  Toggles: {}
                }
```

And within the code behind do this:

```
JavaScriptRegistrar javaScriptRegistrar = GetJavaScriptRegistrar();
javaScriptRegistrar.Register("MyCompany.Toggles.ShowNameDiv", true);
```

But I only get `'undefined'` on that variable. (GetJavaScriptRegistrar is a wrapper for ScriptManager).

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do? 
Am I going about this the wrong way?
Is there a better alternative that will get me the same benefit?

Keep in mind this is old code, and I cannot do a whole page rewrite. I am trying to make an incremental step that I might use to use as an example that I can show to my coworkers.

Comment: Why do you need to store C# data into JavaScript? Depending on the reason we can suggest good alternatives to getting data into javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's difficult to figure what could be the problem without knowing what those pieces of code exactly do (expecially JavascriptRegistrar).

One possible problem is maybe the scope of the javascript "namespace" you declare.
By using the "var" keyword, you're not making the namespace global, it's only defined in the closure it's defined into.
I suppose the javascript code that the JavascriptRegistrar class registers expects a global variable and does not find any so it returns `undefined`.

Here a piece of code to "expose" gloabally you're variable:

```
(function(window, undefined) {

    var myCompany = {
                        Toggles: {}
                    };

    window.MyCompany = myCompany;

})(window);
```